# ClassCast Exception: Subclass Implementation is throwing Exception while invoking Superclass method

Tags: java, generics

I have created an abstract class Foo .
Now I want a String Implementation of the above generic class .But I am getting a ClassCast Exception when I run the code .

```
public abstract class Foo<T> {

    abstract void add(T ... elements); //warning :Type safety: Potential heap pollution via varargs parameter elements
    void addUnlessNull(T ... elements) //warning :Type safety: Potential heap pollution via varargs parameter elements
    {
        for(T element:elements)
        {
            if(element!=null)
                add(element); // Warning:Type safety: A generic array of T is created for a varargs parameter
        }
    }
}



public class StringFoo extends Foo<String> {

    private List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    void add(String... elements) {
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(elements));

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StringFoo ss=new StringFoo();
        ss.addUnlessNull("Hello","World"); //Class Cast Exception 
    }

}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
    at StringFoo.add(StringFoo.java:1)
    at Foo.addUnlessNull(Foo.java:10)
    at StringFoo.main(StringFoo.java:19)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. Which Java version are you using?

Comment: @Eran I am using JDK8  and Eclipse-Photon. Eclipse behaviour is really strange .After you comment when I tried to save my class the compile time error is no more there . But I get a ClassCast exception now

Comment: Only public and protected methods are inherited from super to subclass, and package-private (no modifier) methods are only inherited if both super and subclass are in the same package. Might your `Foo` and `StringFoo` classes be in different packages?

Comment: @Vulcan  : Thanks but i am using same package . Now after recompiling the compile error is no more . But I get a class cast exception when I run the code . I have edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why but I think I know the reason. When you call `add(element)`, the `element` is packed into `Object[] { element }` and then pass to `add` method. So there is a `ClassCastException` from `Object[]` to `String[]`.

Below is a solution which is not good but it should solve your problem.

```
if(element != null) {
    Object arr = Array.newInstance(element.getClass(), 1);
    Array.set(arr, 0, element);
    add((T[]) arr);
}
```

I have tested on JDK 10, there is still a `ClassCastException`, the above code can eliminate this exception.

## UPDATE

I have written a simple example that will also produce `ClassCastException`:

```
abstract class A<T> {
    public void test(T t) { f(t); } 
    public abstract void f(T... ts);
}

class B extends A<String> {
    @Override
    public void f(String[] s) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B().test("");
    }
}
```

I checked the methods of B using reflection, there are three related methods:

```
public void B.f(java.lang.Object[])
public void B.f(java.lang.String[])
public void A.test(java.lang.Object)
```

when I call `new B().test("")`, it will call `public void A.test(java.lang.Object)`. In this method, it then calls `f(t)`, which will actually call `public void B.f(java.lang.Object[])`. That's because `t` is treated as `Object` (though it is `String`). So `t` is packed into `Object[]` instead of `String[]`. However, the actual method in class `B` is `public void B.f(java.lang.String[])`, so there is a `ClassCastException`.

I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, I'm not able to find something in JLS.